# Eclipse Mars: Unable to read repository at http://vaadin.com/eclipse/plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin, eclipse-mars

I tried to install Vaadin plugin on Eclipse Mars.
I got this error..

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>   session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>   Unable to read repository at http://vaadin.com/eclipse/plugins/com.vaadin.designer_1.0.4.jar.
>   Connection reset
>   Unable to read repository at http://vaadin.com/eclipse/plugins/com.vaadin.designer.editor_1.0.4.jar.
>   Read timed out
>   Unable to read repository at http://vaadin.com/eclipse/plugins/com.vaadin.wysiwyg.eclipse_2.3.2.201503060752.jar.
>   Connection reset

I also changed -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true in my ini file. Still I face this issue.
Any idea on how to fix this issue? I'm using Win 7 64 bit / Jdk 7

Comment: Sounds like a temporary network problem. Have you tried again later?

Comment: @ArturSignell  I tried now. Still getting the same issue. 
Connection reset

Comment: I am getting same error but still no solution found. :(

Comment: By adding -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true in eclipse.ini solved the issue for me on Mars + jdk8

Answer (score 0):

Try dragging and dropping the image below into the UI of a running eclipse

[image]

For reference: check here